# How to handle continue statement in threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

Below code is used to move the data from local system to external hard drives. Client's requirement is to use threading for the same so as to speed up the copy of pages / minute.

I am facing one issue. I used `continue` statement under while loop which is not acceptable under thread. Can someone please suggest alternative of the same.

Thanks.

```
    private void PromoteMain(TextWriter streamWriter)
    {
        string driveLetterString;
        driveLetterString = GetExternalDrive();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(driveLetterString))
        {

            DataSet dataSet;
            DateTime startSnooze;
            DataRow row;
            string imageIdString;
            string reelIdString;
            string destImagePathString;
            string[] strArrays;
            int i;
            string fileName;
            string[] strArrays3;
            string[] strArrays4;
            bool flag;
            string[] strArrays5;
            bool flag1;
            string[] strArrays6;
            bool flag2;
            string[] files;
            TimeSpan timeSpan1;
            IEnumerator iEnumerator1;
            string[] stringArray1;
            IDisposable iDisposable1;
            dataSet = this.GetImagesFromDatabase();
            if (((dataSet != null) && (dataSet.Tables.Count != 0)) && (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0))
            {
                iEnumerator1 = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.GetEnumerator();
                try
                {
                    #region goto L_05A9
                    //goto L_05A9;
                    while (iEnumerator1.MoveNext())
                    {
                        driveLetterString = GetExternalDrive();
                        new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(driveLetterString))
                            {
                                row = ((DataRow)iEnumerator1.Current);
                                imageIdString = row["imageid"].ToString();
                                reelIdString = row["reelid"].ToString();
                                destImagePathString = row["destimagepath"].ToString();
                                if (!Directory.Exists(destImagePathString))
                                {
                                    if (this.stringBuilderFail.Length > 0)
                                    {
                                        StringBuilder stringBuilder7 = this.stringBuilderFail.Append(",");
                                    }
                                    StringBuilder stringBuilder8 = this.stringBuilderFail.Append(imageIdString);
                                    this._lblFailed.Text = Convert.ToString(((int)(Convert.ToInt32(this._lblFailed.Text) + 1)));
                                    if (this.stringBuilderFail.Length > 7000)
                                    {
                                        this.UpdateImagesInDatabase(this.stringBuilderFail.ToString(), "5");
                                        StringBuilder stringBuilder9 = this.stringBuilderFail.Remove(0, this.stringBuilderFail.Length);
                                    }
                                    this.RefreshFormView();
                                    continue;
                                }
                                if (!Directory.Exists((driveLetterString + "newspaper\\" + reelIdString + "\\")))
                                {
                                    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo1 = Directory.CreateDirectory((driveLetterString + "newspaper\\" + reelIdString + "\\"));
                                }
                                strArrays = new string[] { ".pdf", ".html", "_clean.html", "_lx.jpg" };
                                for (i = 0; (i < strArrays.Length); i++)
                                {
                                    fileName = strArrays[i];
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (i != 2)
                                        {
                                            strArrays3 = new string[] { driveLetterString, "newspaper\\", reelIdString, "\\", imageIdString, fileName };
                                            File.Copy((destImagePathString + imageIdString + fileName), string.Concat(strArrays3));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                    }
                                }
                                strArrays4 = new string[] { driveLetterString, "newspaper\\", reelIdString, "\\", imageIdString, ".pdf" };
                                flag = File.Exists(string.Concat(strArrays4));
                                strArrays5 = new string[] { driveLetterString, "newspaper\\", reelIdString, "\\", imageIdString, "_lx.jpg" };
                                flag1 = File.Exists(string.Concat(strArrays5));
                                strArrays6 = new string[] { driveLetterString, "newspaper\\", reelIdString, "\\", imageIdString, ".html" };
                                flag2 = File.Exists(string.Concat(strArrays6));
                                if ((flag && flag1) && flag2)
                                {
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine(imageIdString);
                                    if (this.stringBuilderSuccess.Length > 0)
                                    {
                                        StringBuilder stringBuilder3 = this.stringBuilderSuccess.Append(",");
                                    }
                                    StringBuilder stringBuilder4 = this.stringBuilderSuccess.Append(imageIdString);
                                    this._lblPromoted.Text = Convert.ToString(((int)(Convert.ToInt32(this._lblPromoted.Text) + 1)));
                                    #region goto L_0453
                                    L_0453();
                                    continue;
                                    #endregion
                                }
                                files = Directory.GetFiles((driveLetterString + "newspaper\\" + reelIdString + "\\"), (imageIdString + "*.*"));
                                stringArray1 = files;
                                foreach (string str6 in stringArray1)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        File.Delete(str6);
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                    }
                                }
                                if (this.stringBuilderFail.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = this.stringBuilderFail.Append(",");
                                }
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = this.stringBuilderFail.Append(imageIdString);
                                this._lblFailed.Text = Convert.ToString(((int)(Convert.ToInt32(this._lblFailed.Text) + 1)));
                                #region goto L_0453
                                L_0453();
                                continue;
                                #endregion
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            };
                        }).Start();
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
                finally
                {
                    iDisposable1 = (iEnumerator1 as IDisposable);
                    if (iDisposable1 != null)
                    {
                        iDisposable1.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                if (this.stringBuilderSuccess.Length > 0)
                {
                    this.UpdateImagesInDatabase(this.stringBuilderSuccess.ToString(), "3");
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder10 = this.stringBuilderSuccess.Remove(0, this.stringBuilderSuccess.Length);
                }
                if (this.stringBuilderFail.Length > 0)
                {
                    this.UpdateImagesInDatabase(this.stringBuilderFail.ToString(), "5");
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder11 = this.stringBuilderFail.Remove(0, this.stringBuilderFail.Length);
                }
                this.RefreshFormView();
                #region goto L_0671
                PromoteMain(streamWriter);
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                startSnooze = DateTime.Now;
                timeSpan1 = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startSnooze);
                while (timeSpan1.TotalSeconds < 300D)
                {
                    timeSpan1 = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startSnooze);
                    Thread.Sleep(125);
                    Application.DoEvents();

                }
                PromoteMain(streamWriter);
            }
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("There is no space in selected drives");
        //    //there is no space in any external drive
        //}
    }

    private void L_0453()
    {
        if (this.stringBuilderSuccess.Length > 7000)
        {
            this.UpdateImagesInDatabase(this.stringBuilderSuccess.ToString(), "3");
            StringBuilder stringBuilder5 = this.stringBuilderSuccess.Remove(0, this.stringBuilderSuccess.Length);
        }
        if (this.stringBuilderFail.Length > 7000)
        {
            this.UpdateImagesInDatabase(this.stringBuilderFail.ToString(), "5");
            StringBuilder stringBuilder6 = this.stringBuilderFail.Remove(0, this.stringBuilderFail.Length);
        }
        this.RefreshFormView();
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is not acceptable"?

Comment: This question is basically asking us to fix your decompiled code. Show you understand what you're doing and ask a specific question, or go back to the drawing board and rewrite this functionality from scratch. You aren't learning anything from this and it won't be helpful for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the continue statement with a return. This will complete the execution of the thread. Now I don't know how this continue statement ended up there but you can't actually continue since the operations are running in parallel. You should also extract this line

```
row = ((DataRow)iEnumerator1.Current);
```

or you risk the enumerator to change from another thread before it executes. You may also want to try Parallel.Foreach to reduce possible errors and get more effective execution. Even better would be to use async methods with async IO (as opposed to methods that use threads) and use Task.WaitAll to wait for them to complete.